# How to get custom generate Id from table after insert in spring jdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-jdbc

I am inserting one row by getting max Id from table before insert and I will get the same inserted Id back once it is inserted.I will insert in another table with the Id I got.

```
public Boolean saveParentComponentDetails(MultiAdminComponent adminComponentListBean) {
        System.out.println("admincomp "+adminComponentListBean.getActionId());
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        int idvalue=0;
        String key[] = {"COMPONENT_ID"};
        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
            idvalue=jdbcTemplate.update(  new PreparedStatementCreator() {

            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

                PreparedStatement ps =
                        connection.prepareStatement(queriesConstants.SAVE_PARENT_COMPONENT_DETAILS,key);
                    ps.setString(1, adminComponentListBean.getRowId());
                    ps.setString(2, adminComponentListBean.getComponentIdentification());
                    ps.setString(3, adminComponentListBean.getComponentName());
                    ps.setString(4,adminComponentListBean.getComponentType());
                    ps.setString(5, adminComponentListBean.getComponentState());
                    ps.setInt(6, adminComponentListBean.getRevision());
                    return ps;
                }
            },
            keyHolder);
            Long newPersonId = keyHolder.getKey().longValue();

        int idvalues=jdbcTemplate.update(queriesConstants.SAVE_COMPONENT_TO_ACTION, new Object[] {

                adminComponentListBean.getActionId(),
                newPersonId,
                "test",
                1,0
            });

        return idvalue>0;

 }
```

My Query is :-

> INSERT INTO COMPONENT_MASTER
>   (COMPONENT_ID,ROW_ID,COMPONENT_IDENTIFICATION,COMPONENT_NAME,COMPONENT_TYPE,COMPONENT_STATE,FECHA_DE_CREACION,REVISION)
>   SELECT MAX(COMPONENT_ID) + 1,?,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,? FROM
>   COMPONENT_MASTER

The error is:-

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
12:32:49,105 ERROR [stderr] (default task-26) 
12:32:49,106 ERROR [stderr] (default task-26)   at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:91)
12:32:49,107 ERROR [stderr] (default task-26)   at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
12:32:49,108 ERROR [stderr] (default task-26)   at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
12:32:49,108 ERROR [stderr] (default task-26)   at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:645)
12:32:49,108 ERROR [stderr] (default task-26)   at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:900)
12:32:49,108 ERROR [stderr] (default task-26)   at com.caja.creditprocess.daoimpl.AdminComponentDAOImpl.saveParentComponentDetails(AdminComponentDAOImpl.java:55)
12:32:49,108 ERROR [stderr] (default task-26)   at com.caja.creditprocess.adminmanager.AdminComponentEjb.saveComponentDetails(AdminComponentEjb.java:41)
12:32:49,108 ERROR [stderr] (default task-26)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
12:32:49,108 ERROR [stderr] (default task-26)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
12:32:49,108 ERROR [stderr] (default task-26)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
12:32:49,108 ERROR [stderr] (default task-26)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the raw queries which you plan to do?  Maybe there is another way of achieving your goal.

Comment: Sorry I did not Understand

Comment: Multi query business operations introduce all sorts of complexities.  If you could do a single query here, your life might be easier.

Comment: `connection.prepareStatement(queriesConstants.SAVE_PARENT_COMPONENT_DETAILS,key);` 
replace key ->  `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz Getting the same exception

Comment: If the ComponentId is Primary key then it is working, But I should not keep that column as primary key